# How do I filter characters for ListView label editing?

Tags: c#, listview, character

I've tried using Form.KeyPreview but the characters types while ListView label editing do not make it to the form's event handlers.  I would really like to prevent certain characters from being added to the label.

Answer (score 3):

This is technically possible, it requires fairly nasty pinvoke.  Use SendMessage() in your BeginLabelEdit event handler to send LVM_GETEDITCONTROL.  The return value is the handle to the edit control that the list view created.  You can then use that for the AssignHandle() argument of a class derived from NativeWindow.  Whose WndProc() method you can override to listen for WM_KEYDOWN/UP and WM_CHAR messages.  Call the ReleaseHandle() method in your AfterLabelEdit event handler.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declarations you'll need.

The simple Winforms' way is to validate the entered label text.  Implement a handler for the AfterLabelEdit event and set e.Cancel = true if you are not happy.